# Parse-Server file URL is doesnt' change

Tags: swift, mongodb, parse-server

I develop iOS application with use parse-server; my all connection looks successful; all tables get without problems but FILE attach doesn't work;

When I clicked download; file open http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/files/myappID/f******** and doesnt show image; when I change 127.0.0.1 replace live IP image show.

I search all config files on parse-server and mongo db but find not any 127.0.0.1 settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try more methods and my friend find solution; we think that event for bitnami. Now the image open with line URL and can show.

[image]